# secondary level routing in node js changes root directory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

In my web project I am using angular JS and node JS both at the same time.

For routing my url in **Angular JS** I have used the below code

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/expert/:expertname*", {
    templateUrl : "public/views/individual_expert.html",
    controller:"usercontroller"
})
.otherwise({
        redirectTo:"/home"
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

In the above case the url generated is as follows and the page is displayed properly.

> http://localhost:3002/expert/58200b0f3574801df4ef767c

This same thing is executed when I refresh my page with the same url from browser my **NODE JS** code is executed. The code snippet as below

```
app.get('/expert/:expertname',function(req,res){
    if(req.session.usersession!=null){
        if(req.session.usersession.type=="Member")
            res.sendfile('index/member_index.html');
        else if(req.session.usersession.type=="Expert")
            res.sendfile('index/expert_index.html');
        else if(req.session.usersession.type =="Admin")
            res.sendfile('index/admin_index.html');
        else
            res.sendfile('index/visitor_index.html');
    }
    else
        res.sendfile('index/visitor_index.html');
});
```

At this time the errors I see on my browser are as follows

1.) All my CSS paths are changed.

2.) All my JS paths are changed.

The thing which I noticed was that it was changing my root directory with the "expert" and trying to search all the import in that directory.

I am stuck at this for long. Thank you in advance for helping me out.

You can comment if you don't get my question correctly.

Comment: Please add the html code where you link to your css and js. And URLs you expect.

Comment: If you have the links starting with dot `.` like this `./css/style.css` then remove the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the view html page, have `/css/style.css` instead of normal `css/style.css`